# What is CDI (Weld) equivalent for Guice's Names.bindProperties(Binder, Properties)?

Tags: java, guice, cdi, jboss-weld, weld

There's a convenient method in Google Guice which allows binding of properties in one call:

```
Names.bindProperties(binder(), myProperties);
```

which are then injectable by annotation:

```
@Inject
@Named("my.properties.server.url")
private String serverUrl;
```

Is there an equivalent method in CDI (implemented by Weld) or something even better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in core CDI, but DeltaSpike's ConfigProperty (https://cwiki.apache.org/DeltaSpike/temporary-documentation.html#TemporaryDocumentation-@ConfigProperty) will probably do what you want.